# try to run Appium on real device but got Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-ios

I have problem while automation iOS on real device , during i starting test I got erorr `Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.` I also try to sign WebDriveragent but the issue is still exist.
here is the log of Appium

```
[![> Xcode\] Testing started on ' iPhone 6s Pink' \[Xcode\]  \[Xcode\] Testing
> failed: \[Xcode\]     Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a
> development team. Select a development team in the Signing &
> Capabilities editor. \[Xcode\]    WebDriverAgentRunner: \[Xcode\]
>       WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app encountered an error (Failed to
> install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: The file
> “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is
> no such file. The file doesn’t exist. (Underlying error: The operation
> couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory))) \[Xcode\]  \[Xcode\]
> ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED ** \[Xcode\]  \[Xcode\]  \[XCUITest\] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null' \[debug\] \[BaseDriver\] Event
> 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1576751453184 (17:30:53 GMT+0700 (Indochina
> Time)) \[debug\] \[XCUITest\] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of
> xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65 \[debug\] \[XCUITest\]
> xcodebuild error message: \[debug\] \[XCUITest\]  \[debug\] \[XCUITest\]
> 2019-12-19 17:30:53.133 xcodebuild\[13095:284322\] Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file
> “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is
> no such file."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/keo.sidara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa27214ee50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
> Code=2 "No such file or directory"}} \[debug\] \[XCUITest\] Test session
> results, code coverage, and logs: \[debug\] \[XCUITest\]
>   /Users/keo.sidara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019.12.19_17-30-52-+0700.xcresult
> \[debug\] \[XCUITest\] Testing started on ' iPhone 6s Pink' \[debug\]
> \[XCUITest\] Testing failed: \[debug\] \[XCUITest\]   Signing for
> "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a development team. Select a
> development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. \[debug\]
> \[XCUITest\]  WebDriverAgentRunner: \[debug\] \[XCUITest\]
>       WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app encountered an error (Failed to
> install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: The file
> “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is
> no such file. The file doesn’t exist. (Underlying error: The operation
> couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory))) \[debug\] \[XCUITest\]
> ** TEST EXECUTE FAILED **". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md.
> Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if
> it is installed and reboot the device. \[XCUITest\] Quitting and
> uninstalling WebDriverAgent \[XCUITest\] Shutting down sub-processes
> \[XCUITest\] Shutting down iproxy process (pid 13094) \[debug\] \[XCUITest\]
> iproxy exited with code 'null' \[debug\] \[XCUITest\] Removing WDA
> application from device \[XCUITest\] Error: Unable to launch
> WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with
> code 65 \[XCUITest\] xcodebuild error message: \[XCUITest\]  \[XCUITest\]
> 2019-12-19 17:30:53.133 xcodebuild\[13095:284322\] Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file
> “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is
> no such file."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/keo.sidara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa27214ee50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
> Code=2 "No such file or directory"}} \[XCUITest\] Test session results,
> code coverage, and logs: \[XCUITest\]
>   /Users/keo.sidara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019.12.19_17-30-52-+0700.xcresult
> \[XCUITest\] Testing started on ' iPhone 6s Pink' \[XCUITest\] Testing
> failed: \[XCUITest\]  Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a
> development team. Select a development team in the Signing &
> Capabilities editor. \[XCUITest\]     WebDriverAgentRunner: \[XCUITest\]
>       WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app encountered an error (Failed to
> install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: The file
> “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is
> no such file. The file doesn’t exist. (Underlying error: The operation
> couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory))) \[XCUITest\] ** TEST
> EXECUTE FAILED **". Make sure you follow the tutorial at
> https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md.
> Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if
> it is installed and reboot the device. \[XCUITest\]     at
> quitAndUninstall
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:488:13)
> \[XCUITest\]     at
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:518:9
> \[debug\] \[XCUITest\] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles`
> capability to turn on. \[debug\] \[iOSLog\] Stopping iOS log capture
> \[debug\] \[BaseDriver\] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1576751453341
> (17:30:53 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)) \[debug\] \[W3C\] Encountered
> internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent
> because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65 \[debug\]
> \[W3C\] xcodebuild error message: \[debug\] \[W3C\]  \[debug\] \[W3C\]
> 2019-12-19 17:30:53.133 xcodebuild\[13095:284322\] Error
> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file
> “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is
> no such file."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/keo.sidara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa27214ee50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
> Code=2 "No such file or directory"}} \[debug\] \[W3C\] Test session
> results, code coverage, and logs: \[debug\] \[W3C\]
>   /Users/keo.sidara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/Test-WebDriverAgentRunner-2019.12.19_17-30-52-+0700.xcresult
> \[debug\] \[W3C\] Testing started on ' iPhone 6s Pink' \[debug\] \[W3C\]
> Testing failed: \[debug\] \[W3C\]     Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner"
> requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing
> & Capabilities editor. \[debug\] \[W3C\]  WebDriverAgentRunner: \[debug\]
> \[W3C\]       WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app encountered an error (Failed
> to install or launch the test runner. (Underlying error: The file
> “WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app” couldn’t be opened because there is
> no such file. The file doesn’t exist. (Underlying error: The operation
> couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory))) \[debug\] \[W3C\] **
> TEST EXECUTE FAILED **". Make sure you follow the tutorial at
> https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md.
> Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if
> it is installed and reboot the device. \[debug\] \[W3C\]     at
> quitAndUninstall
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:488:13)
> \[debug\] \[W3C\]     at
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:518:9
> \[HTTP\] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 18368 ms - 3779][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to follow the tutorial [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md). It is printed in your error.

Also try passing in the `useNewWDA` capability

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you build Webdriver agent in your iOS device and test.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).